# Footer class not loading in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

My layout.html.twig section contains all the bootstrap link .In my main twig file below i have used this following code. i am not able to load footer section. What am i doing wrong?

```
{% extends 'HomeBundle:Main:layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}English{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div id="sidebar">
        {% include "HomeBundle:Main:sidebar.html.twig "%}
    </div>

    <div id="site-content">

        {% include "HomeBundle:Main:content.html.twig"%}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
    <div id="footer">
        {% include "HomeBundle:Main:footer.html.twig"%}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and my footer.html.twig file contains

```
{% block footer %}

<div class="site-footer">
           <!--footer html codes --->
</div>

 {% endblock %}
```

My layout.html.twig file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
       <!--bootstrap script-->
    {% endblock %}
    }}" />
</head>
<body>


    {% block body %}

    {% endblock %}
</div>
{% block javascripts %}
    <!-- my js scripts-->


{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an error or something?

Comment: no error but cant load footer bar in the webpage

Comment: "and my footer.twig file contains" or "footer.html.twig"?

Comment: its footer.html.twig. is this the correct way below?
 {% block footer %}
    <div id="footer">
        {% include "HomeBundle:Main:footer.html.twig"%}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `{% block footer %}` and `{% endblock %}` from your `footer.html.twig` file.

Comment: Yup, this makes sense :)

Comment: cant view my footer in webpage while viewing page source

Comment: you must add `{% block footer %}{% endblock %}` somewhere in your `layout.html.twig`.